# PHP - Hours difference is not accurate using DateTime object

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to get difference in hours between two dates using PHP DateTime object but the result is not accurate. One date is the current date time and second is the event date which comes from database. I don't understand on what logic the hours difference is calculated.

Here's my code:

```
<?php
$date1 = new DateTime();
$date2 = new DateTime("2018-09-04 20:37:06");
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($interval);
echo "</pre>";
echo $interval->format('%a Day and %h hours');
?>
```

Output:

```
DateInterval Object
(
    [y] => 0
    [m] => 0
    [d] => 0
    [h] => 3
    [i] => 14
    [s] => 13
    [weekday] => 0
    [weekday_behavior] => 0
    [first_last_day_of] => 0
    [invert] => 1
    [days] => 0
    [special_type] => 0
    [special_amount] => 0
    [have_weekday_relative] => 0
    [have_special_relative] => 0
)

0 Day and 3 hours
```

The script is executed at 08:53 PM (India) i.e. 20:53:00 but the difference is 3 hours. Don't know why?

Comment: Can you show the print_r of both $date1 and $date2?

Comment: Are you sure your default timezone is set properly?

Comment: `var_dump([date_default_timezone_get(), $date1, $date2]);`

Comment: @Devon I was going to ask the same exact question. I did that once and could't figure out why the time was not outputting correctly.

Comment: Oh right! Though, I was using the correct timezone for my current datetime as `$date1 = new DateTime('', new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));` but didn't realize that I also need to do the same for database date, so i did `$date2 = new DateTime("2018-09-04 22:59:06", new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata"));` It works now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Indian time this should help :-

```
<?php
$timezone = new DateTimeZone('Asia/Kolkata');
$date1 = new DateTime('now', $timezone);
$date2 = new DateTime("2018-09-04 20:37:06", $timezone);
$interval = $date2->diff($date1);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($interval);
echo "</pre>";
echo $interval->format('%a Day and %h hours');
?>
```

Just use the DateTimeZone('Zone') and it should set the new date to the zone where you are.

Comment: Or, you could pass a DateTimeZone instance as the second argument to DateTime, which I'd recommend so you don't affect any other code that's relying on a different default timezone.  My applications are always coded to UTC as the default.

Comment: I fixed it for you

Comment: Oh My bad Always in a hurry. Thanks :)